# google-drive-ruby: upload file to a folder duplicates the file in the folder and root path

Tags: ruby, google-drive-api

I have writen a Ruby script to lookup for documents with a given date and upload them to Google Drive by using the google-drive-ruby gem. I have a folder inside of the gdrive root path where I want to place the files, and I access it using collection_by_title and then uploading the file by using the .add method.

The problem is that the files are being uploaded each one two times, one to the folder I want and another one to the root path of my GDrive. Any thoughts?

This is the method where the file gets uploaded:

```
def upload_document(file, folder_code)
  folder = @session.collection_by_title("#{folder_code}")
  path = "#{@basedir}/#{folder_code}/#{file}"
  folder.add(@session.upload_from_file(path, file, convert: false)) 
end
```

EDIT: Methods and variables translated to english.

Each time the method upload_document is triggered, one copy of the file gets uploaded to the folder and another copy gets uploaded to the root path of gdrive.

Example: Method upload_document gets called providing the file (454327.pdf) and the code of the folder where it has to be uploaded in gdrive ("1"). I build the folder object by using collection_by_title, I build the path where the file is located in my local network, and finally the file gets uploaded using upload_from_file. At this point, two copies of the file had been uploaded, one to the root path of gdrive (which I don't want) and another one to the right folder in gdrive.

Comment: How is the code being called? Can you provide a *reproducible* example?

Comment: Sure, this is the full script in gist: https://gist.github.com/EGimenoS/0f3ab2fdb82a74807f2c941a4c640a05

Comment: Can you please [edit your post](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/44021544/edit) and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Linking to gists is not encouraged, as that link may not be accessible for future readers - it's better to copy+paste all relevant code into the body of your post.

Comment: It would also be much easier to understand that code if the methods/variables were written in English. StackOverflow [is an English site](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/07/23/non-english-question-policy/).

Comment: (Because it's not English, I only semi-understand that code ... but surely the problem has obviously got something to do with the fact that you're calling the method twice, as I suspected! `subir_lote(1); subir_lote(5)`)

Comment: Sure, I will fix it right away. Tom, the problem is not related to calling the method twice. This is because I have two subfolders, so I have to run twice but writing in different folders. The porblem is that every file gets uploaded to the folder I want ("1" or "5") but they also gets uploaded to the root

Comment: Are you saying that simply writing:  `folder.add(@session.upload_from_file(ruta, file, convert: false))` uploads the file twice, to two locations? I haven't bothered to try, because I highly doubt that .... Can you please confirm exactly what behaviour you are seeing from a **minimal** code example?

Comment: Exactly Tom, is this particular line of code. I have just run the script again now and I'm just seeing how this happens as the files get uploaded.

Comment: are you sure the file is uploaded twice vs being uploaded to both parents (1 and root). Check the file ids

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I received an answer from the gem creator explaining what is happening and my script is finally working as I expected.

https://github.com/gimite/google-drive-ruby/issues/260

The thing is that the file is firstly uploaded to the root by default and then .add just moves the file to the selected collection, so the file needs to be removed from root after the move operation is completed.

```
@session.root_collection.remove(file)
```

Comment: 2020 and the answer still actual.